# dollar-o-gram: how is this developed in excel?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, charts, excel, vba

[Reference here](http://dashboardspy.com/?s=dollar%20o%20gram)

I've got a situation where a chart of the dollar-o-gram format would look great.

What is the simplest way to develop this chart ?

I have knowledge of the following:

- Excel VBA
- Reporting Services 2008 R2
- C# (limited)

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this? http://how.best-free-information.com/2009/04/how-to-create-a-heat-map-in-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a treemap (or hybrid thereof).  Microsoft Research has a tool that purports to give you treemap capabilities:

- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/3f3ed95e-26d8-4616-a06c-b609df29756f/default.aspx

And there's a popular Excel web site that has a limited trial you can download and then purchase for $15 if it works for you.  I won't list the site here, but a web search for "Excel Tree Map" will point you in the right direction.

Even better would be make your tool web publishable using D3 or a similar Javascript library:

- http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html